# .click() in a <div> in a <div> does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#A').click(function () {
    $('#A1').prepend('<div class="AcL" id=' + i + '>Hello<span class="RmMe" id="' + i + '" style="margin-left:20px; cursor:pointer;">X</span></div>');
    i++;
});

$('.RmMe').click(function () {
    alert("OK");
});

<div id="A1"></div>
```

Any idea why the click is not working?

Comment: Could you tell us what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `.delegate()` or `.live()` because you are attempting to bind a handler to an element that does not yet exist.

```
$('#A').click(function() {
    $('#A1').prepend('<div class="AcL" id='+i+'>Hello<span class="RmMe" id="'+i+'" style="margin-left:20px; cursor:pointer;">X</span></div>');
    i++;        
});

$('.RmMe').live('click', function() { alert( 'OK' ); });
```

Try that.

EDIT:

However, should you be using jQuery 1.7+, the `.on` method is the preferred approach: See post from xdazz

```
$('.RmMe').on('click', function () {
    alert("OK");
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Definitely **not `.live()`**, rather `.delegate()`, and if jQuery version is >= 1.7, then `.on()` is the solution.

Comment: @Tadeck - I did note that `.live()` is deprecated in another comment

Comment: @BarryChapman: Maybe, but it should be a part of the answer (otherwise the answer itself is not that valuable as votes suggest).

Comment: `.on` is available in the latest version of jQuery. What version are you using?

Comment: yeah, you will want to use `.live` as that became available in 1.3

Answer (score 3):

Try use [.on<sup>Doc</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.RmMe').on('click', function () {
    alert("OK");
});
```

Comment: The most up-to-date answer here :)

Comment: He will need to use `$.live` since he is on jQuery 1.3.2, `$.on` became available in 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
$('.RmMe').on("click",function(){
     alert("OK");
});
```

because this element does not exist when your DOM is created, it is inserted afterwards and you cannot bind click to the element which does not exist. .live adds an event listener for you, which makes it easy to achieve the task you want.

Comment: .live() is deprecated however, proceed with caution. $.delegate() is the defacto replacement.